# Firebase not using correct config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    // I have config living here
}

const firebaseConfigDev = {
    // I have dev config
}

let config
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config = firebaseConfig
} else {
    config = firebaseConfigDev
}

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfigDev)
}
```

for some reason when my app starts it's not getting the correct config? I mean the `config` var is correct at the top. but the actual app is still pulling data from my first database. even tried restarting my whole app, shutting it down etc. it still pulls from that. infact when I comment out all the above code. it still somehow is using that config.

the only thing I have in the file now is:

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
export const firebaseAuth = auth
export const firebaseMessaging = messaging
export const firebaseDatabase = database
```

yet somehow it still knows about my config? how? I've got no config anywhere else in the app. how can this happen?

Comment: Please check your .firebaserc and firebase.json file to see if you have any settings left over from your old project. Try to create a new project with Firebase CLI. Does this error still persist?

Comment: I literally only have a firebase.js tho? I've created another project which shows up here: `firebase projects:list` can I assign my current one to use another in here somehow?

Comment: I think you can. I have had similar situation before but I opted to create a new project and copied my code over from the my old project. You can try to see if you can change the default project from Firebase CLI. You can try: `firebase use <PROJECT_ALIAS>` to set an active project.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have a `.env` file lying around somewhere that is exporting the config for your other firebase instance?

Comment: nope no `.env` anywhere. this is so weird